# changing text of edit box in list view on button click in android

Tags: android-layout, android-listview

I am using a `ListView`, in which i have inflated another `layout template` which contains `2 Images, an edit text, a correction button , and 2 more buttons,` one of which is quick edit button and now I want `on click on this quick edit button` the edit text should become editable and the `correction button should become visible.` can u please help me.

**From the comments, for easy reading:**

```
mv.quick_edit = (ImageButton)convertView.findViewById
    (R.id.gateway_list_info_image_button_temp);     
mv.quick_edit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { 
 @Override 
 public void onClick(View v) { 
    MyViewHolder m = new MyViewHolder(); 
    m.correct_button.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); 
    m.edit_text.setText("text changed"); 
 }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

in the adapter's `getView` method, i believe you have:

```
editText = (EditText)mView.findViewById(id here);
btnEdit= (Button)mView.findViewById(id here);
```

set the `onClickListener()` of the button in the `getView` method, and inside the onclick, set visibility to `invisible` or `gone`, for the other button you mentioned, and set the `setEnabled` method to true for the editText.

I hope this much clue helps.

**EDIT:**

For using a viewHolder in your code, please refer to [this](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/09/android-viewholder-pattern-example.html?ModPagespeed=noscript)

**Code Snippets:**

```
if(convertView==null){

    // inflate the layout
    LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) mContext).getLayoutInflater();
    convertView = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);

    // well set up the ViewHolder
    viewHolder = new ViewHolderItem();
    viewHolder.textViewItem = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textViewItem);

    // store the holder with the view.
    convertView.setTag(viewHolder);

}else{
    // we've just avoided calling findViewById() on resource everytime
    // just use the viewHolder
    viewHolder = (ViewHolderItem) convertView.getTag();
}
```

It is after the else block that you define the `onClickListeners` and use `viewHolder.editText.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE)`

Comment: because in onclick method mView is showing error... as it is defined ooutside the onclick method

Comment: Cannot refer to a non-final variable convertView inside an inner class defined in a different method

Comment: please refer to  the edit and the link, i believe it will help.

Comment: cannot refer to non-final variable in that case, add final before the variable. But i still insist that you visit the link and make the changes.

Comment: yes... I have also tried it earlier.. but then it give an error in onclick method for viewHolder.

Comment: "Cannot refer to a non-final variable myviewholder inside an inner class defined in a different method" same error occurs

Comment: mView, in your case would be convert_view if i am not wrong.

Comment: do you mind posting how you have declared the convertview and the button?

Comment: public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
  
  MyViewHolder myviewholder = new MyViewHolder();

  inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
    .getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
  if (convertView == null) {
   convertView = inflater.inflate(
     R.layout.activity_gateway_list_template, null);

   myviewholder.gateway_list_name_edit_text = (EditText) convertView
     .findViewById(R.id.gateway_list_name_text_view_temp);
myviewholder.gateway_list_correct_button=(ImageButton) convertView.findViewById(R.id.gateway_list_name_correct_button);

Comment: myviewholder.gateway_list_info_icon_image_button
     .setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

      @Override
      public void onClick(View v) {
       // TODO Auto-generated method stub
       MyViewHolder m= new MyViewHolder();
       m.gateway_list_correct_button.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
       m.gateway_list_name_edit_text.setText("hello");
       
      }
     });

Comment: change public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)  to public View getView(int position, final View convertView, ViewGroup parent)

Comment: and you do not need MyViewHolder m= new MyViewHolder(); inside the onClick

Comment: By doing as u said....in the line:-
The final local variable convertView cannot be assigned. It must be blank and not using a compound assignment

Comment: at this line the above error comes:-   convertView = inflater.inflate(
     R.layout.activity_gateway_list_template, null);

Comment: yes, you will get the error since convertView is declared as final and you cannot modify final variables. Instead, create a new view, like this view = convertView, and then check if view == null, if yes, then inflate it.. like in the answer here. And then use the view variable and not convertView variable